# catching errors during string parsing

Tags: haskell

I want to parse String to get Int and I use this:

```
string2int :: String -> Int
string2int str = read str::Int
```

Now I want to catch paring exception/error as SIMPLY as possible.
I tried:

```
import qualified Control.Exception as E

eVal <- try (print (string2int "a")) :: IO (Either E.SomeException ())
   case eVal of
      Left e -> do { putStrLn "exception"; }
      Right n -> do { putStrLn "good"; }
```

But compiler says `couldn't match expected type 'E.SomeException()'
with actual type E.IOException`.

What am I doing wrong?

Ok I don't know how to use it for my problem: I want somthing like this:

```
loadfunction = do
{
   x <- string2int getLine
   if( failed parsing int ) call somefunction
   y <- string2int getLine
  if( failed parsing int ) call somefunction

  otherfunction x y
}
```

I dont know how to do it using your answers...

Answer (score 7):

You're using `try` imported from the old exceptions mechanism, but are trying to use its result type as if it was using the new extensible Control.Exception mechanism. Use `E.try` instead.

You should ideally import Control.Exception like this:

```
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import Control.Exception
```

and remove all imports of Control.OldException. Then you can use its functions directly without worrying about any clashes.

By the way, you don't have to use IO exceptions to handle read errors; you can use `reads` instead:

```
reads :: (Read a) => String -> [(a, String)]
```

Here's how I'd write your code with `reads`:

```
case reads "a" of
  [(a, "")] -> do
    print a
    putStrLn "good"
  _ -> putStrLn "exception"
```

The fact that `reads` returns a list is [a little confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689560/in-what-scenarios-does-haskells-reads-return-more-than-one-list-item); practically, you can think of it as returning `Maybe (a, String)` instead. If you want a version using `Maybe`, you can define it like this:

```
readMaybe :: (Read a) => String -> Maybe a
readMaybe s =
  case reads s of
    [(a, "")] -> Just a
    _ -> Nothing
```

which makes your code become:

```
case readMaybe "a" of
  Just a -> do
    print a
    putStrLn "good"
  Nothing -> putStrLn "exception"
```

(You can also define `readMaybe` as `listToMaybe . map fst . filter (null . snd) . reads` like dave4420 did; they'll be equivalent in practice, since none of the standard `Read` instances ever return lists of more than one element.)

In general, you should try and use pure error-handling methods like this whenever possible, and only use IO exceptions when there's really no other option, or you're dealing with IO-specific code (like file/network handling, etc.). However, if you want to stick with exceptions, using `E.try` instead should fix your error.

---

Based on your updated question, however, exceptions might be the right way to go after all; something like [ErrorT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html) would also work, but if you're already doing everything in IO to start with, then there's no harm in using exceptions. So I would write your example like this:

```
loadfunction = do
  line1 <- getLine
  x <- string2int line1
  line2 <- getLine
  y <- string2int line2
  otherfunction x y
```

and use `E.catch` to handle the exceptions it throws; take a look at [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html#v:catch) for `catch` to see how to do that.

Comment: This is strange - as I uderstand this function if parsing is ok returns a parsed number otherwise it returns some default number... It is stupid cause when I want to get a Double for example what default number should I return to know that parsing failed???

Comment: @user606521: `readWithDefault` was just meant as an example, not something you should actually use in your code; I've updated my answer to hopefully explain a bit better.

Comment: More useful would be `readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a` where `readMaybe = listToMaybe . map fst . filter (null . snd) . reads` and `listToMaybe` is from `Data.Maybe`. Then you get `Nothing` when the parse fails, or `Just x` when the parse succeeds.

Comment: This readMaybe looks nice but how I can use it? Can you post a simple example?

Comment: @user606521: I've expanded my answer with an example of how to rewrite your code with `readMaybe`. It's basically the same as using `reads`.

Comment: Ok I don't know how to use it for my problem : I want somthing like this:

loadfunction = do
{
   x <- string2int getLine
   if( failed parsing int ) call somefunction
   y <- string2int getLine
   if( failed parsing int ) call somefunction


}

Comment: Ok I don't know how to use it for my problem : I want somthing like this:

    loadfunction = do
    {
       x <- string2int getLine
       if( failed parsing int ) call somefunction
       y <- string2int getLine
      if( failed parsing int ) call somefunction

      otherfunction x y
   }

I dont know how to do it using your anserws...